# inserting jquery string into object id:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I changed the id of the object id below.. I'm trying to change a video upon click:

```
<object id="aeroVideo" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="480" />
  <param name="height" value="270" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />  
</object>

<div id="pic2"> 
  <div id="pic2a"></div> 
  <div id="pic2b"></div>   
</div> <!-- end of pic2 -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {   

var aeroVideo = $("#aeroVideo");

$('#pic2a').click(function(){
console.log("inside pic2a");

if (aeroVideo.length == 0){
aeroVideo = "myExperience3427230656001";
console.log("inside pic2a without variable set");
}
else if (aeroVideo.length != 0){
aeroVideo = "myExperience3427230656001";
console.log("inside pic2a with variable set");
}

});

$('#pic2b').click(function(){
console.log("inside pic2b");

if (aeroVideo.length == 0){
aeroVideo = "myExperience3427216723001";
console.log("inside pic2b without variable set");
}
else if (aeroVideo.length != 0){
aeroVideo = "myExperience3427216723001";
console.log("inside pic2b with variable set");
}

});

});


</script>
```

The console when ran tells me that I am inside the pic2a or pic2b with variable set (never without variable set) but it isn't changing the video at all like it should on inserting the video's string name...

Comment: All your code appears to do is set the variable aeroVideo to a string within an if condition, and nothing else.

Comment: hard to tell what your expectations are, your code doesn't make any sense by itself

Comment: how would I then make sure the code is putting the variable back where it's suppose to go in the object id?

Comment: I would like the object id="aeroVideo" to change to the string that is provided so that it calls the correct video that is associated with this string.

Comment: Since when does an object ID determine the video being played? Isn't that a param?

Comment: Depends on what library is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `aeroVideo` to a string value there, not changing the ID.

You want to change this: `aeroVideo = 'myExperience3427230656001';`

To this: `aeroVideo.attr('id', 'myExperience3427230656001');`.

Also, `aeroVideo.length == 0` returns `true` if aeroVideo is empty (jQuery did not find it), so you probably just want `aeroVideo.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Improvise the question. Looks like the code trying to set a string to aeroVideo. Atleast it has to work with the attributes of the DOM object